# R error : arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r

So I am trying to operate a function over a few columns of a data frame, using a for loop.

```
z <- function(x) gsub("[^\\.\\d]", "", x, perl = TRUE)
data <- cbind(data[1:2], for(i in seq(3, 9)) {y(data[[i]])})
```

I keep running into the error as mentioned in the subject

```
arguments imply differing number of rows
```

The number of rows in all my columns are same.

I tried to use lapply for this, but though it works, it converts the column types over which I apply the function to factor. The columns are numerical values, but are originally read as characters from the file (they are stored as such). So when I try to convert to numbers after using lapply, I get number of levels as output (like, 1,2,3...)

Any suggestions, using either the for loop, or lapply are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
> dput(head(data,3))
structure(list(MCF.Channel.Grouping = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("(Other)", 
"Direct", "Display", "Email", "Organic Search", "Paid Search", 
"Referral", "Social Network"), class = "factor"), Device.Category = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("desktop", "mobile", "tablet"), class = "factor"), 
Spend = c("A$503,172.17", "A$375,940.43", "A$92,560.94"), 
Clicks = c("1,545,416", "1,037,740", "291,314"), Impressions = c("7,328,657", 
"3,787,612", "1,178,508"), Data.Driven.Conversions = c("1,697,814.32", 
"1,540,810.43", "430,738.63"), Data.Driven.CPA = c("A$0.30", 
"A$0.24", "A$0.21"), Data.Driven.Conversion.Value = c("A$12,815,842.66", 
"A$13,883,073.58", "A$3,804,800.15"), Data.Driven.ROAS = c("2547.01%", 
"3692.89%", "4110.59%")), .Names = c("MCF.Channel.Grouping", 
"Device.Category", "Spend", "Clicks", "Impressions", "Data.Driven.Conversions", 
"Data.Driven.CPA", "Data.Driven.Conversion.Value", "Data.Driven.ROAS"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why is this data.table/dplyr related?

Comment: I have suggestion for you to post a `dput` of object `data` from your workspace

Comment: Sorry, removing those tags. I was typing another question in the same window, dplr related, but then I figured that out.

Comment: Try `data[-(1:2)] <- lapply(data[-(1:2)], z) `

Comment: That worked, thank you @PierreLafortune ! May I ask why my way didn't work the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
data[-(1:2)] <- lapply(data[-(1:2)], z)
```

The function is run on columns that are not the first or second. The output is assigned to the same subset in the data.

The original method did not work because the `for` loop does not result in saved output. Check by trying to save it as a variable:

```
x <- for(i in seq(3, 9)) {z(data[[i]])}
x
NULL
```

Even though we saved the contents of the loop, nothing was captured. The loop ran then dumped the results. To see how a loop could work, we can assign values within:

```
for ( i in 3:9) data[,i] <- z(data[,i])
```